# Page.IsValid always return false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have cause validation true on button. And I am checking the `Page.IsValid` in c# code. But its always returning false value?

Answer (score 25):

Here is a code snippet that helped me debug my issue:

```
foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.Validators)
{
    if (validator.Enabled && !validator.IsValid)
    {
        // Put a breakpoint here
        string clientID = validator.ClientID;
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me find my issue.  I had a commented out form validator in the .aspx page but it was still rendering/counting it as a validator, this probably saved me hours of annoyance!!

Answer (score 22):

I know its too late, Hope some one will benefit

If you have **Requiredfieldvalidators** in webpage, you need to set **validataiongroup** attribute to the each **RequiredValidator**.

And then in code you've to check

```
Page.Validate("validategroupname");
if(!Page.IsValid()){
 // your code
}
```

this solves issue

Comment: IsValid() is not a valid method. Just use Page.IsValid.

Answer (score 3):

Have you called [Page.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validate.aspx) before you check its valid state?

Comment: No I did not called Page.validate.

Comment: Can you provide me some code.
@sashaeve , I need to have causevalidation true.

Comment: You have to call Page.Validate always befor you check if page.isValid.

Answer (score 2):

If your button has `CauseValidation = "true"` and you have some another required controls the behaviour is expected. Try to set `CauseValidation = "false"` or check `ValidationGroup` property of button and associated controls ([explanation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx)).

Comment: I've added a link with validation group behavior explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be too late but: Did you have a hidden validator?

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred for me with a commented out asp.net validator. 
e.g.

```
<!--
<asp:label id="labName" runat="server" Text="Name"
AssociatedControlID="tbName"></asp:label> <asp:textbox id="tbName"
runat="server"></asp:textbox> <asp:requiredfieldvalidator
id="ReqFieldValID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbName"
ErrorMessage="Please enter your name"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
-->
```

In spite of having a validator wrapped in an HTML comment, my page still failed validation due to the commented validator.

**Solution:** Add a validation summary to identify the problem. Remove the commented validator to resolve the problem.