# page.Isvalid always return false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have two buttons and two separate validation groups for each button. I kept `EnableClientScript=false` on each requiredfield validator of the textboxes. I have c# code like below

```
void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Validate("LoginAccountGroup");

    if (this.Page.IsValid)
    {
    }
}

void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Validate("CreateAccountGroup");

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

My question is this `Page.Isvalid` is always returning false in the c# code. How to make it work

Comment: Do you have other controls with validations aside from that two?
because the page.validate statement returns true when all of the validators are true.

Comment: Can't you set the ValidationGroup directly on the buttons in the markup (the .aspx page)?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500656/page-isvalid-always-return-false

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
protected bool IsGroupValid(string sValidationGroup)
{
    Page.Validate(sValidationGroup);
    foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.GetValidators(sValidationGroup))
    {
        if (!validator.IsValid)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```